# react-query, refetch don't trigger useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I want to `refetch` the data after save is succeeded.

here is the demo that demonstrates the issue -

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-orla-h9scuc?file=/src/index.js

Issue here is useEffect not gets triggered after `data` changes. So the log from line `111`
never happens...

Is this behaviour expected?? If not What am I doing wrong??

Also If this behaviour is expected then how to get the latest data programmatically?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `react-query` but my guess is that `useEffect` isn't called because `data` doesn't actually change. You refetch, but the result didn't change, so nothing needs to change.

Comment: @JatinParmar, Is it expected behaviour? Is it meant to updated in background only??

Comment: i have checked and code inside useEffect get executed finely

Comment: inside the codesandbox open the console and click on refetch button you will see console.log will updated

Comment: After clicking on `refetch` data button?? Are you sure?

Comment: Why you need this `useEffect`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Query uses structural sharing out of the box.

Please refer below links for more details:

https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-render-optimizations#structural-sharing
https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you already re-fetch the same data with the same reference because react-query gets it from the cache, So according to `useEffect` the `data` doesn't change at all, and will not re-execute.

**So, That's the expected behavior.**

Comment: So, How to fetch data imperatively, Such as If a user wants to update data manually after clicking on the button.

Comment: Check the network tab. You will see that requests fires, but it returns the same data, so that why useEffect is not ruining. Change data on a server and the refetch data.

Comment: do you mean `react-query` does a full value comparison?? Because `React.useEffect` don't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about React-Query but in RTK Query after using `refetch`, for this kind of behavior, you should pass `isFetching` to `useEffect`. This works like a charm and `useEffect` runs again when refetching is done.